# Javascript set date for next 2 days

Tags: javascript, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker and my code is:

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('#start_date').datepicker({
onRender: function(date) {
return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
}
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
checkin.hide();
}).data('datepicker');

var checkin1 = $('#end_date').datepicker({
onRender: function(date) {
return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
}
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
checkin1.hide();
}).data('datepicker');
```

Its start from today date.

Now I want to start from tomorrow after day or set next 5 days. How to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

```
var addDays = new Date();
addDays.setDate(addDays.getDate() + 6);  //add six days
```

Then set this date to your datepicker

```
$("#start_date").datepicker("setDate", addDays);
```

It is not enough to set only the date, inorder to [update](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/methods.html?highlight=setDate#update) the UI add the below code

```
$("#start_date").datepicker('update');
```

Do all these after initialising the *bootstrap datepicker*.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var date = new Date(); // now
date.setDate( date.getDate() + 6); //Add six days
```

And then use it on your date picker.

Comment: Thanks Pablo Santa Cruz. This works fine. Is it possible to select that instead of today in datepicker?

Comment: Sure. You can use datepicker's `setDate`. Take a look at this: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz Bootstrap itself has its own `setDate` and you can have a look at its [documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/methods.html?highlight=setDate#update).  Whereas in your comment above is about jQuery UI datepicker.